# How to set zoomFactor in selenium + phantomjs?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

**Phantomjs Version**: 1.9.7 
**Selenium Version**: 2.40.0

Setting zoomFactor works well when I directly call phamtomjs with `page.zoomFactor` set in .js file:

**Works well**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    page.zoomFactor = 0.25;
    page.render('test.png')
    phantom.exit();
});
```

However it doesn't work when this is set in `desired_capabilities` in selenium:

**Does not work**

```
DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.zoomFactor'] = 0.25
driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
driver.quit()
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't work either:

```
driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS(
    desired_capabilities={'phantomjs.page.zoomFactor': 0.25}
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities={'zoomFactor': 0.25})`?

Comment: yes I tried this but it's also not working.